# How can I find the words I type most frequently?

Tags: autocomplete, typing

Many programs can save you some typing by setting up shortcuts for commonly typed words. For example you could always replace `@gm` with `@gmail.com`. I'm having trouble coming up with a list of things I type frequently and I'm looking for an automated way to discover good candidates.

Answer (score 2):

**Sounds like you'd love AutoHotkey's [AutoCorrect](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#AutoCorrect) script.**

> The following script uses hotstrings
>   to correct about 4700 common English
>   misspellings on-the-fly. It also
>   includes a Win+H hotkey to make it
>   easy to add more misspellings

**If you really want to know what your most commonly typed words are:**

1.) Grab a keylogger that will log to flat files in a plain text format, such as [pykeylogger](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pykeylogger/index.php?title=Main_Page). Note that it can also use delimiters for easier parsing such as CSV. Run it for a day or however long you want until you have enough data to make your word preference more obvious.

2.) And then use this simple program I quickly threw together to count the words (assumes CSV file):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
my %unique = ();

open FH,"< data.txt" or die $!;

while (<FH>)
{
  chomp;
  my @words = split/,/,$_;
  foreach(@words)
  {
      $unique{$_}++;
  }
}

close FH;

foreach(reverse sort {$unique{$a} <=> $unique{$b}} keys %unique)
{
    print "$_ => $unique{$_}\n";
}
```

That will go through each line in a CSV format file, and create a hash containing every word in the file along with how many times it occurs.

Sample input:

```
test,test,test,word,test,other,something,test
something,test,word,test,test
word,test
```

Sample output:

```
john@awesome:~$ chmod +x count.pl
john@awesome:~$ ./count.pl
test => 9
word => 3
something => 2
other => 1
```

Comment: That's the most readable Perl code I've ever seen. :)